# Add element to list depending on rule?

Tags: list

I understand it allows many facts to be written and a possibility tree created- is it possible to do this:

i would like to add value to list depending whether rule returns true or false?

could some person please show me some small code which can explain this?

thank

Comment: Please [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to your previous questions. It's considered courtesy to those writing answers.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you want to generate a list with all the mortals. It can be done with the following code:

```
% facts  
human(victor).
human(peroni).
human(hugo).

% rule
mortal(X) :-
        human(X).

% add X to a list only if rule mortal(X) is true.
add(X,L,[X|L]) :-
        mortal(X).
```

**Example**

```
? add( victor, [hugo], Result).
Result = [victor, hugo].

? add( peroni, [], Result).
Result = [peroni].
```